# How can I implement native (rectangle) ads in App Lovin SDK?

Tags: ios, swift, applovin

I could implement banner, interstitial, and video reward ads in Swift with using App Lovin SDK and reading it.
https://dash.applovin.com/documentation/mediation/ios/getting-started

But there is no documentation to implement native ads (rectangle ads, 300x250). And I couldn't choose "Native" when I create new unit ID.

How can I make native (rectangle) ads with using App Lovin SDK?

Answer (score 0):

MRECs (300x250 ads) aren't supported through mediation at this time.